# which javascript library to include in order to solve "URL" not resoleved

Tags: javascript

i trying to use this turturial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob in order to load blob(which represents image) to canvas, but the intellij compiler isn't recognaize the "URL" variable (Unresoleved variable or type URL).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/URL so maybe use `window.URL` instead.

Comment: So is the problem an error being thrown in your browser, or IntelliJ just not recognizing `URL` as valid? Note that `URL` is not from a library, but part of JavaScript language.

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

```
function resolve(url, base_url) {
var doc      = document
, old_base = doc.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]
, old_href = old_base && old_base.href
, doc_head = doc.head || doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
, our_base = old_base || doc_head.appendChild(doc.createElement('base'))
, resolver = doc.createElement('a')
, resolved_url
;
our_base.href = base_url || '';
resolver.href = url;
resolved_url  = resolver.href; // browser magic at work here

if (old_base) old_base.href = old_href;
else doc_head.removeChild(our_base);
return resolved_url;
}
```